# Visual Studio Code - git colors & project hierarchy

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

There are a lot of different colors for the different files in my project hierarchy but so far I have been unable to find an overview of what all of these colors mean. Where can I find more information on this?

Edit: Please see this screenshot:

[image: colors]

It has the colors red ("9+"), green ("U"), light yellow ("M"), dark yellow ("2"). Would be interested to have an overview of what all those colors refer to

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the colors you're referring to?

Comment: Please see this screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/SOCVvUC . It has the colors red ("9+"), green ("U"), light yellow ("M"), dark yellow ("2"). Would be interested to have an overview of what all those colors refer to

Answer (score 4):

## These are called **Git Status in File Explorer**:

1. They will show up once you initialize git in your project.
2. They are not more than decorations that can help you to understand the status of each file in your project.

### Playing with Git Decoration

1. You can show/hide decorations with the `git.decorations.enabled` setting.
2. You can show/hide colors with the `explorer.decorations.colors` setting.
3. You can show/hide colors with the badges `explorer.decorations.badges` settings.

### Git Decoration Meanings

#### - Badges Decoration:

1. ' ' --> Unmodified
2. M --> Modified
3. A --> Added
4. D --> Deleted
5. R --> Renamed
6. C --> Copied
7. U --> Untracked (Updated but Unmerged)

#### - Colors Decoration:

1. Green Color --> Created Newly.
2. Yellow/Orange Color --> Modified Files
3. Transparent-ish --> Ignored Files (Not Created Newly, and Not Modified).

### ***Illustrations***

1. The red color is not related to Git Status. However, it is related to Visual Studio Code and it means that you have error(s) in this file.
2. The number you have in the red color (9+) is related to the number of errors you have in the file, when the number of errors goes more than 9 errors it will be shown as 9+.
3. Regarding Green color in Git Status: When you create a new file it will be shown in green color until you stage and commit that file, it will become transparent and then if you change on the same file it will become yellow/orange since it is not newly created anymore. Therefore, the newly created file is new until you commit them.

I hope my explanation was clear and not boring. Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

All these colors are [depending on your theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#git-colors), so there is no generic description of what the colors mean.

The colors for the git status have been [introduced in v1.18](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_git-status-in-file-explorer) with the appended character being the [short format of `git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status/2.2.3#_short_format) ("A"=added, "M"=modified).

A number next to a filename is an [indicator for problems](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/782#issuecomment-351420874) in that file. Even though it is not documented anywhere, the default theme colors are red for errors and yellow for warnings.